# WPF - Tooltips are being clipped to window size

Tags: wpf, tooltip

I've seen that WPF tooltips can be shown as being not clipped to the window they're viewed in, but for me they are clipping to the window.

http://wpf.2000things.com/2013/07/17/865-tooltip-can-extend-beyond-window-boundaries/

My results:

```
<TextBlock Text="?" ToolTip="Denotes if initial dividend calculation will be rounded to nearest $0.01" />
```

[image]

Any ideas why this is showing within the borders of the window? Every other example I can find has the tooltip showing above the window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much later, I found the solution. Applying the following style will wrap the text, and stop the tooltip from being truncated.

```
    <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just curious..what happens if you wrap a AdornerDecorator  around your control or you whole view?

```
<AdornerDecorator>

</AdornerDecorator>
```

Comment: This didn't have any effect for me. The best thing I came up with was to explicitly designate the tooltip as a textblock with wrapping, but it still is confined to the window.